# nonPersistent Option, upgrading an App from React Native 0.55 to 0.60.2

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am in the middle of trying to upgrade an app from React-Native 0.55 to 0.60.2 to enable 64 bit support before the Google deadline. When I try to manually upgrade the App, (react-native upgrade only brings it to 0.58) running the expo build gives a response:

error: unknown option `--nonPersistent'

The app builds fine with the older versions, and a grep search of the directory gives no results for the phrase 'nonPersistent.' How do I fix this problem?

react-native upgrade
react-native-git-upgrade
Manually changing package.json

error: unknown option `--nonPersistent'

Comment: are you using expo?

Comment: Can you provide a sample program and steps to produce the error so that readers can reproduce what you see?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Expo, you might need to remove `nonPersistent` option from `packagerOpts` inside `app.json` file.

```
{
  "expo": {
    ...
    "packagerOpts": {
      "nonPersistent": "--nonPersistent", <- remove this
      ...
    }
  ...
}
```

This error happened after I upgraded from Expo SDK 35 to 36.
I forgot what this option was for...

After removing this I can use `expo start` as usual.

Answer (score 0):

For reasons beyond my comprehension, changing the version of react-native in package.json from 0.60.2 to 0.59.9 fixed the issue.